# Does Addintools' Classic Menu for Word, include WordArt, in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Does Office Menu for Word, include WordArt, in Word 2013?

If I go to File..Account, I see it's Ms Office Pro Plus 2013

If I go to Menus to get the menus up(a menus for office feature). And I go to Insert, then I see SmartArt, but not WordArt

[image]

If I go to Insert, I see WordArt, which I want because of the semicircle text feature that I don't think is in SmartArt.

[image]

But I wonder if WordArt is in the menus?

My Menus for Office program seems to support Office 2013.

[image]

Comment: As was pointed out, this is a third-party Add-in that few people answering these questions use. You should ask the manufacturer. Greg Maxey produced a free Add-In for Word that does the same thing at https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/ribbon_menu_control.html. It also does not include WordArt. WordArt was very much redone with the Ribbon versions. It is available on the Ribbon under the Insert Tab. Greg has a page on classic WordArt https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/classic_wordart_in_word2010_2013_documents.html as do I: http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#WordArtAddIn

Comment: The latest version is 9.25 released in 2015. You might want to upgrade. https://www.addintools.com/index.html I do not know whether or not this will include WordArt in the menus. You can ask them. Again, you can access WordArt under the Insert Tab in Word 2013's native UI.

Answer (score 0):

> If I go to Menus to get the menus up(a menus for office feature). And I go to Insert, then I see SmartArt, but not WordArt
>
> [image]

The menu in question is generated by a third-party add-in and does not exist otherwise.  Using the default Ribbon bar, within all supported versions of Office, SmartArt and WordArt are both present.

> But I wonder if WordArt is in the menus?

The menu in question is clearly missing WordArt for some reason.  It's absence is likely an oversight by the author of the add-in.  **Based on the revision history of the add-in it doesn't appear this would be the first time the add-in was missing a menu item.**

Comment: when you say default ribbon do you mean as in my second picture not in a menu, but under insert? would you say the "the insert ribbon"?

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows both SmartArt and WordArt on the Ribbon itself, only the third-party menu, is missing WordArt

Comment: AT Ramhound, so you look at that whole area as "the ribbon", ok. Just getting the lingo.

Comment: @barlop - Yes? Microsoft calls the entire interface the Ribbon bar.